# Share files between Mac OSX and Ubuntu on Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, shared-folders

I have a hackintosh dual booted with ubuntu and I am trying to create a separate (3rd) partition to essentially share files between them and act almost like a usb, since the hackintosh has no wifi. I have tried formating the partition as fat32, hfs, and ext4 but each have problems reading/writing on one or the other OS's. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: You could try [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/2855038/how-to-mount-and-manage-non-native-file-systems-in-os-x-with-fuse.html). However, I think this question would be better suited on AskDifferent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your needs you should try the NTFS<sup>1</sup> and ExFAT<sup>2</sup> file systems. They're both well supported in Linux and OS X<sup>3</sup> (with FUSE on both ends) and don't suffer from the problematic limitations of the FAT family.

If you need help formatting your partition with either of them, give me a comment and I'll look for or write some instructions. You should be fine with the usual tools (`mkfs`, Gnome Disks, GParted), though.

---

<sup>1</sup> NTFS works out of the box on Ubuntu.

<sup>2</sup> Install [exfat-fuse](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/exfat-fuse/) to give Ubuntu the ability to mount ExFAT file systems and [exfat-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/exfat-utils/) to create and manipulate ExFAT file systems.

<sup>3</sup> For instructions on how to use FUSE to mount NTFS and ExFAT file systems on OS X please refer to our sister site [AskDifferent](//apple.stackexchange.com/) or other online resources as they would be off topic here.

Comment: Thank you so much, this might be what I'm looking for, I'll try it out after I finish my homework. So fuse on mac and the NTFS/ExFAT packages for ubuntu should solve any mount problems or such?

Comment: See the update to my answer.